# Преобразование byte[] в int

Tags: java, byte, int, bytearray

Мне нужно преобразовать список типа byte например [-1,8,0,0] в int например 263...
Попробовал вот такой метод

```java
ByteBuffer.wrap(input).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt()
```

И вроде всё работает,до тех пор пока выходной int не превышает 127...после чего происходит что-то странное и этот метод начинает возвращать странные значения,намного выше требуемых...

Comment: `byte[]` это массив правильно?

Comment: а с какой стати это должно быть равно 263? Вот если бы вы использовали [0, 0, 1, 7], то получили бы 263. Для этого не нужно указывать `LITTLE_ENDIAN`. Ну или можно указать `BIG_ENDIAN`.

Comment: @MikhailIonkin с той,что -1 в байтовом представлении это 255...255+8=263...

Comment: @СергейГущин, интересная у вас арифметика преобразований... Откуда вы берете такую информацию?

Comment: @ヒミコ Byte.toUnsignedInt(-1); вернёт 255...

Comment: @СергейГущин, окей, пойдем с другой стороны. Вы знаете как представлен -1 (255) в двоичной системе счисления?

Comment: @ヒミコ ну прям так сходу сказать не смогу...но онлайн-конвертеры всегда в помощь)

Comment: Читайте обновленный ответ, надеюсь теперь вы поймете что там не 263.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того что бы ТС понял почему у него не выходит получить 263 с представленными данными, я напишу ответ такой, что бы можно было понять как происходит преобразование.

Представление целого в двоичной системе счисления:

```
|  1 byte   |  2 byte   |  3 byte   |  4 byte   |
------------------------------------------------- [0]
| 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 |
```

Где нули, это биты, не байты! Значение бита это `0` / `1` ***(как кнопка вкл/выкл)***

Представление числа 255 в двоичной системе выглядит так:

```
|  1 byte   |  2 byte   |  3 byte   |  4 byte   |
------------------------------------------------- [255]
| 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 1111 1111 |
```

Байт же, это кусочек целого:

```
|  1 byte   |
------------- [255]
| 1111 1111 |
```

Когда вы разбиваете целое на такие 4 кусочка, у вас не будет такого, что вы сложили эти 4 байта вместе и получили исходное число. (`255 * 4 = 1 020` когда диапазон `uint32 = 4 294 967 295`)

Далее, когда вы так сказать вынули из целого 4 байта, т.е. разбили его на 4 байта, то вам необходимо вернуть эти байты на место что бы получить исходное число *(при перемешке байт результат будет не тот который ожидался)*, а делается это с использованием сдвигов, т.е. вы берете и с конца заполняете битовые поля т.е.:

```
|  1 byte   |  2 byte   |  3 byte   |  4 byte   |
------------------------------------------------- [0]
| 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 |
<< 24 сдвиг на 24 бита влево
          0 < 24 бит (можете сами посчитать)
| 0000 0000 |
```

Далее, когда вы заполнили первые 8 бит *(`byte == 8 bit`)* нужно отнять `24 - 8 == 16` И сделать тоже самое со вторым байтом:

```
|  1 byte   |  2 byte   |  3 byte   |  4 byte   |
------------------------------------------------- [0]
| 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 |
<< 16 сдвиг на 16 бит влево
                      0 < 16 бит
            | 0000 0000 |
```

3й байт:

```
|  1 byte   |  2 byte   |  3 byte   |  4 byte   |
------------------------------------------------- [0]
| 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 |
<< 8 сдвиг на 8 бит влево
                                  0 < 8 бит
                        | 0000 0000 |
```

4й:

```
|  1 byte   |  2 byte   |  3 byte   |  4 byte   |
------------------------------------------------- [0]
| 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 |
<< 0 (или & num) сдвиг на 0 бит влево
                                              0 < 0 бит
                                    | 1111 1111 |
-------------------------------------------------
| 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 1111 1111 | [255]
```

Только так можно получить обратно то целое число которое вы разбили на байты.

В то время как вы в вопросе привели следующие данные:

```
|  1 byte   |  2 byte   |  3 byte   |  4 byte   |
------------------------------------------------- [-16 252 928]
| 1111 1111 | 0000 1000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 |
```

Comment: не,всё так-же плохо...я бы даже сказал хуже стало)
Выходит число -16252928

Comment: А исходное число?

Comment: Исходное?
На вход подал [-1,8,0,0]
Ожидаемое число 263
Или вы про то как я получил список байт?

Comment: Серьезно? Да я про то как вы получили список байт... Там явно не 263.

Comment: А теперь подставьте `[0, 0, 1, 7]` тогда получите 263

Comment: Ну с получением тут немного сложнее будет)
Я это получаю с программы написанной на другом языке,а если конкретно то на C#...судя по исходному коду,int в byte[] там конвертируется во так:
```
public unsafe static byte[] GetBytes(int value)
  {
   byte[] array = new byte[4];
   fixed (byte\* ptr = array)
   {
    \*(int\*)ptr = value;
   }
   return array;
  }
```
Возможно из-за разности языков и возникают проблемы...

Comment: [0,0,1,7] это BE...а вот LE и вправду 263...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102742/discussion-between---and-).

Comment: Не нужно ли в Java приводить bytes[i] к инту **до** сдвига, чтобы биты не пропали?